# Create javascript bookmarklet with current year/month/date/hour inserted into URL?

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

Have this URL I would like to create a bookmarklet for to access the latest data with variables for current UTC date/time (year, month, day and (hour + 6)):

`https://www.ogimet.com/cgi-bin/gsynres?ind=02464&lang=en&decoded=yes&ndays=2&ano=2021&mes=07&day=07&hora=18`

Is it possible to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Some JavaScript code can do this.
Thankfully setHours() updates the day / month, etc if it is above 24.

```js
    let d = new Date();
    d.setHours(d.getHours() + 6);
    console.log(`https://www.ogimet.com/cgi-bin/gsynres?ind=02464&lang=en&decoded=yes&ndays=2&ano=${d.getFullYear()}&mes=${d.getMonth()}&day=${d.getDate()}&hora=${d.getHours() + 6}`);
```

Using [bookmarkleter](https://chriszarate.github.io/bookmarkleter/) gives us:

```
javascript:void%20function(){let%20a=new%20Date;a.setHours(a.getHours()+6),window.open(`https://www.ogimet.com/cgi-bin/gsynres%3Find=02464%26lang=en%26decoded=yes%26ndays=2%26ano=${a.getFullYear()}%26mes=${a.getMonth()}%26day=${a.getDate()}%26hora=${a.getHours()+6}`)}();
```

Answer (score 0):

Modifying your answer (@ScottJodoin) got it to work, using the `window.open()` method and `getUTC` methods. The website accepted >24 values for hour in the URL, which made `setHours()` needless.

```
let d = new Date();
window.open(`https://www.ogimet.com/cgi-bin/gsynres?ind=02464&lang=en&decoded=yes&ndays=2&ano=${d.getUTCFullYear()}&mes=${d.getUTCMonth()+1}&day=${d.getUTCDate()}&hora=${d.getUTCHours()+6}`,'_self');
```

Conversion in [Bookmarkleter](https://chriszarate.github.io/bookmarkleter/) gives:

```
javascript:void%20function(){let%20a=new%20Date;window.open(`https://www.ogimet.com/cgi-bin/gsynres%3Find=02464%26lang=en%26decoded=yes%26ndays=2%26ano=${a.getUTCFullYear()}%26mes=${a.getUTCMonth()+1}%26day=${a.getUTCDate()}%26hora=${a.getUTCHours()+6}`,%22_self%22)}();
```